# string replace with exception on certain strings

Tags: c#

I have this line of code that I'm using to prepare some CSS file:

```
TheMinifiedCSS = TheMinifiedCSS.Replace("white", "#FFF");
```

The problem is that in CSS, I have this declaration:

```
.SomeClass{white-space:pre-wrap;}
```

How do I change the `.Replace` statement to replace `white` with `#FFF` but to leave `white-space` alone?

Thanks.

Note, I know I can add `TheMinifiedCSS = TheMinifiedCSS.Replace("#FFF-space", "white-space");` but I'm looking for something cleaner.

Comment: If you are doing this to make your CSS file smaller then I'd go as far as to suggest its a waste of time. You'd be much better off just making sure that the file is cached and then leaving it at that unless you are getting massive amounts of users viewing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People keep trying to write rules for things that appear before or after `"white"`, when I think what's desired is that `"white"` is its own token and not part of a selector.

```
Regex.Replace(TheMinifiedCSS, @"(?<![-_a-zA-Z0-9#.])white(?![-_a-zA-Z0-9])", @"#FFF");
```

A more complete rule would implement the entire rule for identifier tokens in CSS, but I think this one covers all keywords.

Here's a slightly trickier test case than has been posted so far:

```
.white> TD { color: white;box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white, inset 0px 0px 5px black; white-space:pre-wrap; }
BODY { background: url('test.png'),white; }
```

Even trickier, and not handled by my example, are filenames.

```
BODY
{
  background-color:white;
  background-image:url('almost white, but not really.png');
}
```

To get that right, you probably need a full CSS parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression for it. I think this is the best way for you. Here is the link where you can get more detailed information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

I am not really strong with building patterns for regular expressions, but you can try this sample

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var inputText = @"white-space: 0; color: white;
                    box-shadow: 10px 20px  30px white, inset 0px 0px 5px black;";

    inputText = ChangeColor(inputText, "white", "#FFF");
}

private static string ChangeColor(string css, string oldColor, string newColor)
{
    // Rule 1
    var pattern1 = string.Format(@"(color)(\s*):(\s*){0}(\s*)", oldColor);
    var replacement = string.Format("$1 : {0}", newColor);

    var rgx = new Regex(pattern1);
    css = rgx.Replace(css, replacement);

    // Rule 2
    var pattern2 = string.Format(@"([\d]*)px(\s*)([\d]*)px(\s*)([\d]*)px(\s*){0}", oldColor);
    var replacement2 = string.Format("$1px $3px $5px {0}", newColor);

    rgx = new Regex(pattern2);
    css = rgx.Replace(css, replacement2);

    return css;
}
```

Comment: There's also this case: box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white, inset 0px 0px 5px black;

Answer (score 1):

Regex can make things a lot more complicated. Here is a solution that works. Has solution for comments and strings as well.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = ".white> TD { color: white;box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white, inset 0px 0px 5px black; white-space:pre-wrap; background-image='white black \" white \"'}";
        Console.WriteLine("Before: " + test);
        test = replaceInCSS(test, "white", "green");
        Console.WriteLine("After: " + test);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string replaceInCSS(string text, string replace, string replacement)
    {
        char[] forceBefore = new char[]{ '\n', '\t', ';', '{', ' ', ':', ','};
        char[] forceAfter = new char[] { ';', '}', ' ', ','};

        int index = text.IndexOf(replace, 0);
        while (index != -1)
        {
            if (!indexWithinStringOrComment(text, index))
            {
                int afterPos = index + replace.Length;
                bool beforeOk = false, afterOk = false;

                if (index > 0 && forceBefore.Contains<char>(text[index - 1]))
                    beforeOk = true;
                if (afterPos < text.Length - 1 && forceAfter.Contains<char>(text[afterPos]))
                    afterOk = true;

                if ((index == 0 || beforeOk) &&
                    (afterPos == text.Length - 1 || afterOk))
                {
                    text = text.Remove(index, replace.Length);
                    text = text.Insert(index, replacement);
                }
            }

            index = text.IndexOf(replace, index + 1);
        }

        return text;
    }

    static bool indexWithinStringOrComment(string text, int index)
    {
        bool insideStrSimple = false;
        bool insideStrDouble = false;
        bool insideStrComment = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
        {
            string subStr = text.Substring(i, 2);

            if (text[i] == '\'' && !insideStrDouble && !insideStrComment)
                insideStrSimple = !insideStrSimple;
            else if (text[i] == '"' && !insideStrSimple && !insideStrComment)
                insideStrDouble = !insideStrDouble;
            else if (text.Substring(i, 2) == "/*" && !insideStrDouble && !insideStrSimple)
                insideStrComment = true;
            else if (text.Substring(i, 2) == "*/" && insideStrComment)
                insideStrComment = false;
        }

        return insideStrDouble || insideStrSimple || insideStrComment;
    }
```

Output:

```
Before: .white> TD { color: white;box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white, inset 0px 0px 5px black; white-space:pre-wrap;  background-image='white black \" white \"'}
After: .white> TD { color: green;box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px green, inset 0px 0px 5px black; white-space:pre-wrap;  background-image='white black \" white \"'}
```

---

Edit:
There we go. Inside string problem is also solved. This should work to replace any css property. Edit again: Added fix for comments.

Comment: And what do you get as result?  The ".white > TD" is supposed to NOT be changed.

Comment: Done. Took 24min though :(

Comment: I'm impressed that you went to that effort, but sadly this approach is pretty fragile.  This CSS validates but your code can't handle it: `background: url('test.png'),white;`  Please note that you've basically reinvented the lookahead and lookbehind features of regular expressions, so that your logic could be described by `(?<=\n|\t[;{ ])white(?=[;} ,])`

Comment: Yeah true. I solved the string problem now. Also your example with ,white; should work just fine. If ',' should not be allowed before it's just a matter of removing it in forceBefore.

Comment: It's more a case that comma should be allowed before.  I recognize that adjusting that list is easy -- it's also easy in a regular expression.  However, some sort of state machine is the only reasonable approach to handling URL strings; regex falls flat there.

Comment: Agreed. Regex is great as long as the conditions for the operation is not too complicated, like in this instance. The problem I have with Regex is that it can often become really incomprehensible compared to using a function or two.

Comment: Agreed that I wouldn't want to see a regex like that floating in code.  But I can add two lines of comments saying "uses a zero-width lookbehind assertion for foo" and "uses a zero-width lookahead assertion for bar" and still come out much much shorter.  And while the individual parts of your code are easily understood, you'll also need a couple comments to express the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack would be to replace only when it's preceded with a `:`

```
TheMinifiedCSS = TheMinifiedCSS.Replace(": white", ":#FFF");
```

This way it will only replace css-values and not properties.

In my opinion though, the best way is to either use regular expressions or use a CSS parser and completely rebuild the document.

BTW: If you're doing this for learning purposes it's OK, however if you want to use this for production purposes, I strongly advice you to use an existing component that does all this already.

Comment: And what if there's no space after `:`, or there's a tab character, or...  `String.Replace` isn't very good at this.

Comment: Exactly, that why it's a hack and the OP should really use regexes or a CSS-parser

Comment: What happens with box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white, inset 0px 0px 5px black;

Comment: It's the same story, this is a hack. If you want to do it correctly use regexes or a CSS-parser. String.Replace is not flexible enough to handle what you're trying to do.

Comment: So how do write a regex rule for my case? I guess it should say something like "if you find white between ":" and ";" or between ":" and "}" then replace with #FFF

Comment: I'm not an expert in Regexes. Usually when I need to do something like this I use this tool: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm
It allows you to build your regex with an editor and you check the results immediately. With some logic and this program you should be able to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Simple... should work for most purposes:

```
TheMinifedCSS = Regex.Replace(TheMinifiedCSS, @":(.*)white(.*);", @":$1#FFF$2;")
```

Basically checks if it's after a colon, then takes all chars until white, replaces and then gets all the chars after and then a semicolon. After that, it puts the `css` around the new bit which is replacing `white` (`#FFF`) and then after that a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

This would be most efficient way to find the string `white` & replace it with `#FFF`

```
TheMinifedCSS = 
Regex.Replace(TheMinifiedCSS, @"(:(.*)(white)(.*);|:[ ]*(white)[ ]*})", @"#FFF");
```

It handles space in between like: `{color:   white}` `{color:white}` both are valid.

You can check this link for further reference: http://regexr.com?34tqv